# Conditional Formatting - Different color to value based on row

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, row

I'm using conditional formatting of color to the value 1. When the value 1 appears in the pair line, the cells are gray. And on the odd line, blue. I have done this manually. How can I do this automatically?

[image]

Comment: assuming a "1" or "TRUE" is used for set of color (and "0"/"FALSE"/empty cell for no color) then (for range J:AM): `=MOD(ROW(J1),2)*J1` will only color on odd rows /// `=MOD(ROW(J1)+1,2)*J1` will only color on even rows

Answer (score 0):

Apply `Conditional Formatting` to the range, as follows:

1. Select the range `B2:H11` *(update range as required)*
2. To apply color to the even rows:

   a. In the ribbon tab `Home`, group `Styles` click the dropdown menu
       on `Conditional Formatting` then select `New Rule` *(see Fig. 1 below)*.

   b. In the dialog box `New Formatting Rule` select Rule Type `Use a formula to determine which cells to format` then in the box below `Format values where this formula is true:` enter this formula `=ISEVEN(ROW())`

   c. Click the `Format…` button to open the `Format Cells` dialog box and set the color to be applied in the `Fill` tab *(see Fig. 2 below)*.
3. To apply color to the odd rows: Repeat all point 2 instructions using this formula: `=NOT(ISEVEN(ROW()))`*(see Fig. 3 below)*.

*Fig. 1* [image]

*Fig. 2* [image]

*Fig. 3* [image]

*Fig. 4* [image]